# Pinterest API app not showing in approved apps

Tags: php, api, pinterest

Recently I have run into a problem with the pinterest api, I am using a library to help me and below is my simple script to authorize my application.

The library I am using is [this one](https://github.com/hansott/pinterest-php)

I would ask in there if the problem had anything to do with the library itself which it does not since it was working until i revoked access to test it, since then it never authorizes.

The code redirects me to the login page and shows the right scopes, but when I approve and go to the pinterest page it does not show any authorized apps.

After my main code (below) there is a simple callback page that collects the access token into the database and then shows the user basic info.

Code used to connect:

```
<?php
session_start();
require "vendor\autoload.php";
use Pinterest\App\Scope;


$client = new Pinterest\Http\BuzzClient();
$auth = new Pinterest\Authentication($client, 'i have my cliend id here', 'i have my client secret here');

$url = $auth->getAuthenticationUrl(
    'i have my redirect uri here',
    array(
        Scope::READ_PUBLIC,
        Scope::WRITE_PUBLIC,
        Scope::READ_RELATIONSHIPS,
        Scope::WRITE_RELATIONSHIPS,
    ),
    'random-string'
);

header('Location: ' . $url);
exit;
?>
```